# Don't have access to all of my static files in Django

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

So, I'm deploying a Django project at PythonAnywhere, using django-tinymce/django-summernote (I've tried both, and get the same error). Everything works as it should locally, but at PythonAnywhere I don't get the rich-text editor I'm supposed to.

I pull up the JavaScript console and noticing a couple of 404 errors. I try to navigate to my static files manually by typing domain.com/static/summernote/summernote.css in my URL field and gets the following 404 error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in Domain.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. ^$ [name='article_list']
2. ^posts/(?P<pk>\d+) [name='post_detail']
3. ^search$ [name='search_result']
4. ^summernote/
5. ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
6. ^admin/

The current path, static/summernote/summernote.css, didn't match any of these.
```

However, when I enter the path to my other CSS or JS files (Which is in the same static directory), the file shows up. Also, entering the path locally (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/summernote/summernote.css) workes fine.

So now I really don't know what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Did u run `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: @DarkSuniuM Yes, but all that did was creating a new directory containing the static files? Do I also need to change the path to static files then?

Comment: In your 404 error there is a path (`^summernote/`), is it a path for your views or maybe it is what your server serving as the static files for summernote ? It may came from the module itself

Comment: @DarkSuniuM It's just according to the summernote documentation. url(r'^summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls'))

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution myself. I don't know if it is the right solution, but at least it works.

First,

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

Then remove APPNAME from the path to the static directory in your web tab. This is probably a very PythonAnywhere specific issue.